# Input stream must not be null exception in gradle project

Tags: android, image, gradle, exception, javafx

I have MainClass

```
public class MainClass extends Application {

    @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

            try{
                Image img = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(".\\build\\resources\\main\\img\\h1.jpg"));
                System.out.println("ok");
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and my image is in `\build\resources\main\img\h1.jpg` directory

my project files:

[image: my project files]

When I run project it gives Input stream must not be null exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resource paths are not separated by `\` Furthermore they start at the resource root. In this case the path `"/img/h1.jpg"` should do the trick assuming your IDE properly includes the resources in the classpath at runtime.

`getResource`(`AsStream`) does not access the data via file path; The data may not be available as file at all, but as entry in a JAR file. If you need to refer to a file that is not included in the classpath, use `File`'s functionality to convert to a URI or use a `FileInputStream`:

```
new Image(new File(".\\build\\resources\\main\\img\\h1.jpg").toURI().toString())
```